# variable redefinition, embedded c

Tags: c, header, embedded, redefinition

I'm working on an embedded c project and am having issues with global variable redefinition.

I've split up the function declarations and definitions into a handful of .h and .c files.  Many of these functions need access to global variables, which are defined in global_vars.h.  Therefore, at the beginning of the header files, inside the #ifndef, #define section, "global_vars.h".  If I don't, as you might imagine I get a bunch of undefined variable errors.

However, even though global_vars.h has the #ifndef _GLOBAL_VARS_H_ #define... #endif, I get redefinition errors for all the global variables.  My guess is that when the linker tries link the various object files, it sees the redefinition due to the #include "global_vars.h" in all the "blah_blah.h" files.  It was my understanding, though, that the #ifndef... takes care of this issue.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to declare the variables in the header, and only define them in one source file.

Comment: Your `global_vars.h` file should be declaring all variables as `extern` then actually define them in a separate module.  I would guess you're not doing this?

Comment: As a sidenote, if you have a "globals" file in your project with non-const globals declared at file scope, it usually indicates that something with the whole program design is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The linker never sees anything in the global_vars.h file, ever, unless -- bad news! -- some of the globals are actually ***defined*** in that file. global_vars.h should hold only ***declarations*** of those global variables, never (well, almost never) their definitions.

In global_vars.h, you should have declarations like:

```
extern int some_global;
```

You are not allowed to have:

```
int some_global;
```

If you have definitions in global_vars.h then, yes, they'll be multiply defined at link time because each of the .c files that #includes global_vars.h will have its own definition of each defined variable.

All of the definitions of the `extern` globals must be in *some* .c file, for sure. Usually it doesn't matter which .c file. Often all of the global-variable definitions are in a file called (surprise!) global_vars.c.

So make sure there aren't any global-variable definitions in global_vars.h and you'll be in good shape.

Answer (score 2):

Is not a good idea to define globals in an H file. Better if you do that in a C or C++ file and you include and H file in other modules with those globals as externals.
Like this>>>

My module c file

```
unsigned short int AGLOBAL = 10; // definer and initializer

void MyFunc(void)
{
  AGLOBAL+=1; // no need to include anything here cause is defined above
  // more .....

}
```

My H file globals.h

```
// this is to include only once
#ifndef MYH
#define MYH
extern unsigned short int AGLOBAL; // no value in here!

#endif
```

Other module c file

```
#include globals.h

char SomeOtherFunc(void)
{
  AGLOBAL+=10; // ok cause its defined by globals.h
  // do more....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So let me start with saying that extern keyword applies to C variables (data objects) and C functions. Basically extern keyword extends the visibility of the C variables and C functions. Probably that’s is the reason why it was named as extern.

Use of extern with C functions. By default, the declaration and definition of a C function have *“extern”* prepended with them. It means even though we don’t use extern with the declaration/definition of C functions, it is present there. 
For example, when we write.

```
int foo(int arg1, char arg2);
```

There’s an extern present in the beginning which is hidden and the compiler treats it as below.

```
extern int foo(int arg1, char arg2);
```

Same is the case with the definition of a C function (Definition of a C function means writing the body of the function). Therefore whenever we define a C function, an extern is present there in the beginning of the function definition. Since the declaration can be done any number of times and definition can be done only once, we can notice that declaration of a function can be added in several C/H files or in a single C/H file several times. But we notice the actual definition of the function only once (i.e. in one file only). And as the extern extends the visibility to the whole program, the functions can be used (called) anywhere in any of the files of the whole program provided the declaration of the function is known. (By knowing the declaration of the function, C compiler knows that the definition of the function exists and it goes ahead to compile the program). 
So that’s all about extern with C functions.

1. Declaration can be done any number of times but definition only once.
2. “extern” keyword is used to extend the visibility of variables/functions().
3. Since functions are visible through out the program by default. The use of extern is not needed in function declaration/definition. Its use is redundant.
4. When extern is used with a variable, it’s only declared not defined.
5. As an exception, when an extern variable is declared with initialization, it is taken as definition of the variable as well.