# Avoid re-definition in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, c-preprocessor

I would like to avoid re-definition from two different include files as follows:

#### File *ABC.h*

```
extern int v=1;
```

#### File *foo.h*

```
#include "ABC.h"
class Foo
#ifdef BLA
: public ABC
#endif

{
    ...
};
```

#### File *bar.h*

```
extern int v=3;
```

#### Main:

```
#define BLA
#include <foo.h>
#include <bar.h>
```

Basically `foo` is a class written by me, and `bar` is a third-party library. But it doesn't seem to work. How should I solve the problem?

Sorry, it's a bit hard to describe, the example is kind of bad as the conflicted parts are actually not variables, but something like `#define` and wrapped in big blocks of code (error message is: "multiple definition of `__vector_17'"). Is there a way to solve it **without using a namespace**?

Comment: using namespace if you want to use both ``v``?

Comment: ...Or giving your own variable a different name? To reflect its different function?

Comment: Edited the question a bit to be more precise...

Comment: Both ABC.h and bar.h has some really complicated stuff inside that I'd rather avoid :(

Comment: Would this SO entry be useful to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378817/variable-redefinition-embedded-c

Answer (score 1):

Using a namespace you can solve this problem:

```
namespace foo
{
    int val =1;
}

namespace bar
{
    int val =3;
}

using namespace foo;

int x = val; //Now x will be assigned with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A namespace is what you need:

```
namespace foo
{
    int v =100;
}

namespace bar
{
    int v =500;
}
```